# Section Headings With Long Titles

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to use latex to write my thesis, and I have modified a template to use, but am having trouble with some of my section headings. Specifically, with the weird spacing between words caused by the section heading being justified, rather than flush left.

I am using the titlesec package and have tried:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\raggedright\large\sffamily\bf}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

I also tried forcing titlesec to make everything raggedright by adding

```
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
```

to my preamble but neither seem to have any effect and the heading text is still strangely spaced. I think it is probably something else within my settings that is taking preference?

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{report}
%-----------------------------------------
%                  Packages
%-----------------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper, scale=1.0, textwidth=145mm, textheight=237mm, layoutvoffset=0pt, layouthoffset=0pt, ignoremp, includehead, marginparsep=0pt, bottom=4cm, top=2cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm, verbose=true, bindingoffset=0pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[toc, page, header]{appendix} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption} 

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN PAGE SETUP
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % sets roman font to Times ('ptm')
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % sets serif font to Helvetica 
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} % sets text type font to Latin Modern Typewriter ('ptm')
\widowpenalty=500 
\clubpenalty=500 
\pretolerance=10000 
\tolerance=2000 %
\emergencystretch=10pt 

\titleformat{\section}{\fillleft\large\sffamily\bf}{\thesection}{1em}{} %formats the section titles 

\begin{document}

\onehalfspace
\chapter[Introduction]{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction} % label for referring to chapter in other parts of the thesis
\section[Importance]{Importance}\label{C1:Intro}
```

Filling in later

```
 \section[Synthesis]{Synthesis of averylongcompoundnamethatis toobigtofitinthisbox}

 blahblahblah

\end{document}
```

[image: Longtitleimage]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Your document is so long, that is hard to tell where the error might be

Comment: Hi. Yeah I know, I think this is where I am having trouble as well. I will try and cut parts out and see if they have an effect.

Comment: I think, it is the `\pretolerance` Please turn it off by adding a `%` before!

Comment: Do you really want hyphenation turned off for the whole thesis?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really like them being added automatically. Is there a better way to do this than what is currently in place? I have edited the main post with a more minimal example.

Comment: If you don't want hyphenation you should set the whole document raggedright, justifying paragraphs with no hyphenation will make a horrible result with over-stretched space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already loading package `sectsty`. Then use

```
\sectionfont{\raggedright\large\sffamily\bfseries}
```

or do *not* load package secsty and `\titleformat` will also work. If you want to allow hyphenation then use:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\sectionfont{\RaggedRight\large\sffamily\bfseries}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to do what I was asking, how come this works while the titlesec seemed to just ignore me?

Comment: Do _not_ load package `secsty` and `titlesec`will also work.

Comment: @user2478, can you spell that out for us? We want to learn how this works.

Answer (score 2):

The `\pretolerance` value is too large, preventing a hyphenation and its consequent line break and therefore stretches the line to break at the next possible position, i.e. at `toobig...`
The problem vanishes after turning it off (by commenting it)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, scale=1.0, textwidth=145mm, textheight=237mm, layoutvoffset=0pt, layouthoffset=0pt, ignoremp, includehead, marginparsep=0pt, bottom=4cm, top=2cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm, verbose=true, bindingoffset=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[toc, page, header]{appendix} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption} 

\newcommand{\mk}[1]{%
%
}


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN PAGE SETUP
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------

% This section is relevant to formatting within chapters
\linespread{1.8} %1.5 line spacing
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % sets roman font to Times ('ptm')
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % sets serif font to Helvetica 
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} % sets text type font to Latin Modern Typewriter ('ptm')
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % retains control of headers and footers
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0.0in} % margin size at header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} % thickness of rule in header line (0pt will make it disappear)
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead{\fancyplain{\leftmark}{\leftmark}} %prints current chapter name in the right header
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\chead{\fancyplain{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % thickness of rule in footer line

\headsep=12pt % Sets distance between header rule and text
\parindent=12pt % Sets indentation for each paragraph
\parskip=0.1in % Sets vertical space before a new paragraph
\widowpenalty=500 % elliminates widows (single lines of a paragraph on the top of the next page), see line below
\clubpenalty=500 % these two lines eliminate widows and orphans from the document, but may affect typesetting quality elsewhere.

%\pretolerance=10000 % turns off hyphenation

\tolerance=2000 % turns off hyphenation
\emergencystretch=10pt % turns off hyphenation


%  The following changes the Chapter Title format 

\titleformat{\section}{\raggedright\large\sffamily\bf}{\thesection}{1em}{} %formats the section titles 

% for a bit more fancy chapter and section titles use the following 12 lines:
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright
}%
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\sffamily}{\small}
\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\bf}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspace
\chapter[Introduction]{Introduction}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction} % label for referring to chapter in other parts of the thesis
\section[Importance]{Importance}\label{C1:Intro}
 Filling in later

 \section[Synthesis]{Synthesis of averylongcompoundnamethatis toobigtofitinthisbox}

 blahblahblah



\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this then causes it to hyphenate halfway through the word - which I was trying to avoid. I would rather the line break between the words and have it all pushed to the left if possible?

Comment: You can use another value of `\pretolerance` at an appropiate place mid-document

Comment: Ok, but then what if I use another compound with a long name later on?

Comment: Is there a more appropriate value to use for the pretolerance? Or does latex generally handle these ok? Sometimes they can be placed strangely.

Comment: Honestly spoken: In nearly 20 years of `TeXing` I was **never** in need of changing `\pretolerance`, so `LaTeX` handles it in most cases correctly  ;-)

Comment: Alright, I will switch it off. What about the other two? \tolerance and \emergencystretch. Do these act in a similar way? In the comments they were tagged as having an effect on hyphenation as well.

Comment: I am still getting an overfull hbox warning for this line (with all three settings commented out. Is this a big issue?

Comment: In my point of view, those values should not changed also, except from a `multicols` environment

Comment: @Dylan: No, not really, as long as the text does not flows over to the margin.

Comment: Ok, I have tried this in my actual document, and while the title is now showing up ok. The main text now has hyphens everywhere. I don't think this should be necessary in a justified document when most of the words being used are short enough to be able to spread apart a bit more. eg. between now appears as be-tween. Am I able to choose to hyphenate titles only?

Comment: @Dylan: You can 'always' provide a manual hyphenation

Comment: Yeah of course. I have ended up turning the pretolerance back on, but have now adjusted it to 2000 instead of 10000. It seems to be happier now. Cheers